# Enable MySQL Performance Monitor

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, monitor, status

I like to collect statistics to analize and improve the overall performance... After installing Xampp 1.8.1 on my Small Server, i was navigating trought phpMyAdmin Panel, and on the panel Monitor - under the Status tab - It shows the following message:

=====

Monitor Refresh Failed

While requesting new chart data the server returned an invalid response. This is most likely because your session expired. Reloading the page and reentering your credentials should help.

=====

I've looked on but i could not find anything related... I've tried to reload the page but without success..

I already made the changes on the MySQL config file to allow those statistics..

Is that because im using it on a **WINDOWS** server?
(unfortunately i cant change it to Linux by now, as i use Active Directory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the problem, but I hunted it down using **FireBug**. The problem was that my PHP didn't load the extension `php_com_dotnet.dll` which can be activated this way:

```
[COM_DOT_NET]

extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
```

Answer (score 2):

This error appears when the response from the AJAX request couldn't be parsed as JSON data. This can be caused by other errors as well. If you have Chrome or Firefox, please check the developer tools/console in the tab Network (Chrome) or Net (Firefox) and look for the ajax request to server_status.php. The Response of that HTTP Request will help a lot to find out whats wrong.

And if your into debugging, this is probably the spot in PMA that fails for you: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/blob/master/js/server_status_monitor.js#L1369

Also, the fact you're using windows is not the cause. I've programmed it to work under windows as well ;-)
The MySQL Server Setting are also unlikely to be the cause of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can still connect to it from a linux client with http://mtop.sourceforge.net/

or, you can enable http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/slow-query-log.html

Comment: As i said, i already enabled the Slow Query Log, the PHPMyAdmin says the configuration is ok, but it shows that message.. I was hoping to use the PHPMyAdmin Status Monitor interface, which is much better to analyze...

Comment: Enabling slow query log dramatically impacts performance. Which metric are you trying to measure?

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly, i discovered that the error was because i was using an Windows Server, it is kind of obvious looking at it now. This panel only works on Linux, thanks for the help from everyone

Comment: Actually you can run it on windows... take a look @Mr.Generation's answer

Comment: Actually, its a little strange.. at the time of this post the performance monitor wouldnt work, but a few weeks ago i tested again and i succeded, on windows! thx!

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem with xampp 1.8.1 on windows.
Solved adding COM_DOT_NET extension to php.ini.
Thanks